# Publishing an npm package that strictly requires a minimum Node version

Tags: node.js, npm

If I write a package I am certain requires Node 4 or higher, I don't want it to be installable with older versions.

I know about the package.json engines field, but that's just advisory (only causes a warning). And enginesStrict has been deprecated.

So what can I do?

One idea is to have a preinstall script that checks the Node version and errors if it's not high enough, preventing installation from continuing. Are there any problems with doing that? And is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you need to do anything at all? Someone who uses it will see that Node v4 is expected, so if it doesn't work they shouldn't be surprised.

Comment: @FelixKling it's very easy to miss a little warning about the expected Node version, especially among a bunch of noise from various packages' postinstall scripts

Comment: Personally I would just add a note to the readme.

Comment: If it makes any difference, this is for a CLI tool, not a reusable module. I don't want people installing my CLI tool if it means, when they first try to use it, they're going to get a confusing error about 'bad syntax' in my code. It's a much better user experience for me to block the installation, and print out a helpful message explaining they need to upgrade their Node and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a good experience, make your CLI entrypoint standard ES5 and CommonJS, detect the node version (`process.version`), and print a detailed and helpful message then exit non-zero. Keep in mind your module may get installed with some node version then the user futzes with nvm or their PATH or whatever and then runs your code under a different version. Thus I think failing nicely at run time is the most important thing. You can also choose to fail at install time if you like.

Comment: Ok thanks. One remaining problem though is if my CLI depends on something like node-sass, which actually builds differently depending on node version. That would mean the user would have to reinstall the CLI after upgrading node anyway. So failing early on preinstall seems best in that case. I might also do a runtime check as you suggest though.

Comment: The node-sass issue I think should be handled by `npm rebuild` which is the official way to deal with install on node version X and try to run on node version Y.